# Python - How to use select() with bs4

Tags: python, select

So I have been trying to figure out scraping abit and still learning. I have created a script where it prints out numbers but some of the numbers has a class that are disabled and what I want to do is that I just want to print out those numbers that has no disabled in "class"

```
try:
    select_tags = bs4.find_all('select', {'autocomplete': 'off'})
except Exception:
    select_tags = []

data_products = []
for select_tag in select_tags:

   test = select_tag.find_all('option')
   for hehe in test[1:]:

       print(hehe)
       print("----------")

       if hehe.select('select > option(.disabled)'):
           print('Skip')
           continue

       try:
           found = hehe.text
           found = found.replace(" ", "")
           found = found.replace("\n", "")
       except Exception:
           found = None

       found_data = {
           "found": found
       }
       data_products.append(found_data)


print(data_products)
```

output:

```
----------
<option class="" value="11_141">
                            (Number 1)                        </option>
----------
<option class="" value="11_142">
                            (Number 2)                        </option>
----------
<option class="" value="11_143">
                            (Number 3)                       </option>
----------
<option class="disabled ReminderRevealButton" value="11_144">
                            (Number 4)                       </option>
----------
<option class="" value="11_145">
                            (Number 5)                        </option>
----------
<option class="disabled ReminderRevealButton" value="11_137">
                            (Number 6)                        </option>
----------
<option class="" value="11_136">
                            (Number 7)                        </option>
----------
```

What I want for output is:

```
(Number 1)
(Number 2)
(Number 3)
#Skip number 4 because it has Disabled
(Number 5)
#Skip number 6 because it has disabled
(Number 7)
```

What do I need to do to be able to solved that?

Comment: @CodeIt Not really. In that thread its ask about how to print each Number one by one and here I am asking how to remove those that includes a name of disabled :)

Comment: Check if the class is on the `option` element is not an option? For instance getting the option element via `find("option")` and check via `if "disabled" in option["class"]: pass`.

Comment: I tried to print out `hehe.find('option')` but the problem is it says None for all items. @Sens4

Comment: it seems like you already have the option element within hehe. So just skip the part with the `find`. `hehe["class"]` should return all classes from the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code skips the options that has disabled class.

```
try:
    select_tags = bs4.find_all('select', {'autocomplete': 'off'})
except Exception:
    select_tags = []

data_products = []
for select_tag in select_tags:

   test = select_tag.find_all('option')
   for hehe in test[1:]:

       if "disabled" not in hehe:
           print(hehe.text)
```

Comment: Hmm. This code just printed the numbers. Number 1 to 7 and it did not skip.

Comment: If hehe.txt returns a string like this `<option class="" value="11_136">
                            (Number 7)                        </option>` then it will check if has disabled class.

Comment: As I can see, When I try to print hehe.text. It prints only the values which in this case is only the Numbers. If you just print hehe then it returns the comment you wrote

Comment: @Hellosiroverthere Please mark it as answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: Sorry for late response. The answer was not fully correct. What you had to do is to add hehe['class'] to make it work! :)